# How to save all the network traffic (both request and response headers) from a website using python

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to find an object that is downloaded into the browser during the loading of a website.

This is the website, https://epco.taleo.net/careersection/alljobs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en,

I'm not very good with web technology and such.

I am trying to save the request and response headers and the actual response using only the link to the website.

If you look at the network traffic, you can see an object `jobsearch.ftl?lang=en` that loads towards the end and you can see the reponse and headers.

Here are the screenshots, of the network event log showing the request and response headers.

[image: network event log]

And the actual response.

[image: response]

These are the objects that I want to save. How can I do that?

I have tried

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromepath = "~/chromedriver/chromedriver"

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromepath, desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get('https://epco.taleo.net/careersection/alljobs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en')

def process_browser_log_entry(entry):
    response = json.loads(entry['message'])['message']
    return response

browser_log = driver.get_log('performance') 
events = [process_browser_log_entry(entry) for entry in browser_log]
events = [event for event in events if 'Network.response' in event['method']]
```

But I only get some of the headers, they look like this,

```
{'method': 'Network.responseReceivedExtraInfo',
  'params': {'blockedCookies': [],
   'headers': {'Cache-Control': 'private',
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
    'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self'",
    'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
    'Date': 'Mon, 27 Sep 2021 18:18:10 GMT',
    'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100',
    'P3P': 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"',
    'Server': 'Taleo Web Server 8',
    'Set-Cookie': 'locale=en; path=/careersection/; secure; HttpOnly',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
    'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=edge',
    'X-XSS-Protection': '1'},
   'headersText': 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Mon, 27 Sep 2021 18:18:10 GMT\r\nServer: Taleo Web Server 8\r\nCache-Control: private\r\nP3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\nSet-Cookie: locale=en; path=/careersection/; secure; HttpOnly\r\nContent-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors \'self\'\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1\r\nX-UA-Compatible: IE=edge\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n',
   'requestId': '1E3CDDE80EE37825EF2D9C909FFFAFF3',
   'resourceIPAddressSpace': 'Public'}},
 {'method': 'Network.responseReceived',
  'params': {'frameId': '1624E6F3E724CA508A6D55D556CBE198',
   'loaderId': '1E3CDDE80EE37825EF2D9C909FFFAFF3',
   'requestId': '1E3CDDE80EE37825EF2D9C909FFFAFF3',
   'response': {'connectionId': 26,
```

They don't contain all the information I can see from the web inspector in chrome.

I want to get the whole response and request headers and the actual response. Is this the correct way? Is there another better way which doesn't use selenium and only requests instead?

Comment: Let me get this - Are you trying to download the response or are you interested in the job ids and description?

Comment: I am more interested in the request AND response headers that are sent and received, the job ids etc are secondary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `selenium-wire` library if you want to use `Selenium` to work with this. However, if you're only concerned for a specific API, then rather than using Selenium, you can use the `requests` library for hitting the API and then print the results of the `request` and `response` headers.

Considering you're looking for the earlier, using the Selenium way, one way to achieve this is using `selenium-wire` library. However, it will give the result for all the background API's/requests being hit - which you can then easily filter after either piping the result to a text file or in terminal itself

Install using `pip install selenium-wire`

Install `webdriver-manager` using `pip install webdriver-manager`

Install Selenium 4 using `pip install selenium==4.0.0.b4`

Use this code

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

svc    = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc)

driver.get('https://epco.taleo.net/careersection/alljobs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en')

for req in driver.requests:
  if req.response:
    print(
      req.url,
      req.response.status_code,
      req.headers,
      req.response.headers
    )
```

which gives a detailed output of all the requests - copying the relavent one -

```
https://epco.taleo.net/careersection/alljobs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en 200 


Host: epco.taleo.net
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8


Date: Tue, 28 Sep 2021 11:14:14 GMT
Server: Taleo Web Server 8
Cache-Control: private
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: locale=en; path=/careersection/; secure; HttpOnly
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-XSS-Protection: 1
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: your answer works perfectly, if you know of any methods not requiring selenium please let me know! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS in selenium. So this will be easier:

```
var req = new XmlHttpRequest();
req.open("get", url_address_string);
req.send();
// when you get your data then:
x.getAllResponseHeaders();
```

XmlHttpRequest is async, so you need some code to consume answer.

Ok here you go:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
headers = driver.execute_script(""" var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var rH;

xhr.addEventListener('loadend', (ev) => {
     window.rH =  xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(); // <-- we assing headers to proprty in window object so then we can use it
    console.log(rH);
    return rH;
})

xhr.open("get", "https://stackoverflow.com/")
xhr.send()
""")
# need to wait bcoz xhr request is async, this is dirty don't do this ;)
time.sleep(5)
# and we now can extract our 'rH' property from window. With javascript
headers = driver.execute_script("""return window.rH""")
# <--- "accept-ranges: bytes\r\ncache-control: private\r\ncontent-encoding: gzip\r\ncontent-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; ....
print(headers)
# headers arejust string but parts of it are separated with \r\n so you need to
# headers.split("\r\n")
# then you will find a list
```

EDIT 2:
You actually dont want HEADERS. When your browser go to desired url, one of the resposne create variable for this page: `_ftl`

When you open Dev tools -> console and type "_ftl" you will se object. Now you want to access it. But this is not that easy - _ftl is deep nested object. So you must pick property of it and try to access . Like:
`a = driver.execute_script("return window._ftl._acts")`
Will result in:
[image]

But accessing data will be hard task, `_ftl` is nested object and  selenium  js serializer can't handle it automatically.

So another answer:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://epco.taleo.net/careersection/alljobs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en"

g = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(g.text)
ftl_script = soup.find_all('script')[-1]
data_you_need =ftl_script.text
```

But this will result in raw string. You still have to find a way how to process it.

Comment: can it be done in python? im not very familiar with javascript

Comment: Honestly, you need to  check docs. But you can execute JS inside Selenioum like: 
`a = driver.executeScript("""return 1""')`
So you `a` variable will be = '1'

Comment: i tried it your way but I am only getting one header, im not getting the header i am looking for.. i also want the response

Comment: ok,  updated. Please check